# AwesomeWM returning to lightdm after trying to log in

Tags: lightdm, awesome

I recently installed AwesomeWM, everything was going fine til I tried to edit the rc.lua. It wouldn't let me save from AwesomeWM so I opened up Unity and saved it from there and when I tried to log back into Awesome it just keeps throwing me back to the lightdm login screen.

I have tried `sudo apt-get remove awesome`and then reinstalling it. I have tried getting a working rc.lua from google and neither of these work.

I don't really know what to do. It just keeps throwing me back to the login box, unity and 2d are both working fine. Very strange inded.

Answer (score 3):

When you tried editing `rc.lua`, were you trying to edit the system-wide one?  I'm guessing you didn't have proper permission to do so and then in Unity you used some GUI method that got around that.  That might have messed up the permissions on the config file so that you can't use it on login; either that, or there's a serious error in your config, although I've never had such a bad error it won't let me login.

Make sure you copy the default system-wide `rc.lua` to `~/.config/awesome/`:

```
cp /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua ~/.config/awesome/
```

Then edit the local copy.  By the way, just because you got someone's `rc.lua` doesn't mean it will work for you.  It depends how much they've customized it.  After modifying your `rc.lua`, you should always run `awesome -k` first, before restarting Awesome.  This will check for basic errors in your configuration, although it's not a perfect check.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
awesome -k
```

reports no errors, i'd try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force lightdm awesome
```